# Route to Edit page in Razor page from EF Auto Scaffold

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am trying to learn the nuances of Razor pages. I scaffolded out a new set of pages from my Equity entity in my model, using the EF CRUD option on add Razor page. This created the usual Index, Edit, Create, Details and Delete pages.

The index view works, and retrieves the sample data.

[image: Index view]

This entity doesnt have a singular Id property, it has a composite primary key using the Symbol and the TradeDate properties. I adjusted my Edit code to get the page to the following.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string symbol, string date)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(symbol) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Equity = await _context.Equities
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Symbol == symbol
                                                    && m.TradeDate == Convert.ToDateTime(date));

        if (Equity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

The Equity entity

```
public class Equity : SecurityBase
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public DateTime TradeDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
}
```

Defined in Fluent Configuration as

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Equity> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(k => new {k.Symbol, k.TradeDate})
            .HasName("PK_Equity");

        builder.Property(u => u.Symbol)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(32);

        builder.Property(u => u.TradeDate)
            .HasColumnType("Date")
            .IsRequired();

        //rest removed for brevity
}
```

When I click on the Edit link for the first data row it creates this url

> https://localhost:44391/EquityTradeData?Symbol=LYFT&TradeDate=8%2F19%2F2019&action=Edit

The url really should look like EquityTradeData/Edit?Symbol=….

**Note:** I manually changed the url to look like above and it is now hitting the OnGet method but the date value from the query string is always null. So there are two problems, that date value is null and the url generated is wrong, it needs the /Edit after the EquityTradeData

from this markup (which I'd like to change to a tag helper if possible)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { Symbol = item.Symbol,TradeDate = item.TradeDate.ToShortDateString()})
```

But clicking on that "Edit" link doesn't do anything, the url changes in the address bar but the page is not re-routed to the Edit page with the Edit form displayed for that selected date.

It stays on the Index page with the sample data displayed.

Everything looks right to me, but I'm not sure how the generated url's work in Razor so I'm assuming that something is amiss in how it is generating the re-routing url.

I tried debugging, but the OnGetAsync method in the Edit.cshtml.cs is never called when I click the Edit link from the index page.

Comment: wondering if this `OnGetAsync(string symbol, string date)` should be this `OnGetAsync(string symbol, DateTime tradeDate)`

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Edit", new { Symbol = item.Symbol, TradeDate = item.TradeDate.ToShortDateString()})` (the overload with the `controllerName` also)? You might also try `OnGetAsync([FromQuery] string symbol, [FromQuery] string date)`

Comment: I've tried all three of the above suggestions and get the same; nothing happens. Page doesn't re-route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned above `@Html.ActionLink` does not build the correct Url and doesn't seem well suited to Razor Pages with Handlers.

I managed to get it working using the following

```
<a asp-page="Edit" asp-page-handler="OnGetAsync" asp-route-symbol="@item.Symbol" asp-route-date="@item.TradeDate.ToShortDateString()">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it with a tag helper (as you mentioned) like this:

```
@{
    var routeData = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {nameof(Model.Symbol), Model.Symbol},
        {nameof(Model.TradeDate), Model.TradeDate}
    };
}
```

Then:

```
<a asp-page="../Edit" asp-all-route-data="@routeData">
```

Reference: [Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper#asp-all-route-data)